# How to determine the memory footprint (size) of a variable?

Tags: php, memory

Is there a function in PHP (or a PHP extension) to find out how much memory a given variable uses? `sizeof` just tells me the number of elements/properties.

`memory_get_usage` helps in that it gives me the memory size used by the *whole* script. Is there a way to do this for a single variable?

Note that this is on a development machine, so loading extensions or debug tools is feasible.

Comment: Edited - it's 5 years later, and some problems are still somewhat unsolved :(

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You Probably need a Memory Profiler. I have gathered information fro SO but I have copied the some important thing which may help you also.

As you probably know, Xdebug dropped the memory profiling support since the 2.* version. Please search for the "removed functions" string here: http://www.xdebug.org/updates.php

> **Removed functions**
>
> Removed support for Memory profiling as that didn't work properly.

## Other Profiler Options

## php-memory-profiler

https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler. This is what I've done on my Ubuntu server to enable it:

```
sudo apt-get install libjudy-dev libjudydebian1
sudo pecl install memprof
echo "extension=memprof.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/memprof.ini
sudo php5enmod memprof
service apache2 restart
```

And then in my code:

```
<?php
memprof_enable();
// do your stuff
memprof_dump_callgrind(fopen("/tmp/callgrind.out", "w"));
```

Finally open the `callgrind.out` file with [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net)

## Using Google gperftools (recommended!)

First of all install the **Google gperftools** by downloading the latest package here: https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/

Then as always:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libunwind-dev -y
./configure
make
make install
```

Now in your code:

```
memprof_enable();

// do your magic

memprof_dump_pprof(fopen("/tmp/profile.heap", "w"));
```

Then open your terminal and launch:

```
pprof --web /tmp/profile.heap
```

*pprof* will create a new window in your existing browser session with something like shown below:

[image: PHP memory profiling with memprof and gperftools]

## Xhprof + Xhgui (the best in my opinion to profile both cpu and memory)

With **Xhprof** and **Xhgui** you can profile the cpu usage as well or just the memory usage if that's your issue at the moment.
It's a very complete solutions, it gives you full control and the logs can be written both on mongo or in the filesystem.

For more details [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787462/php-xdebug-how-to-profile-forked-process/31388948#31388948).

## Blackfire

Blackfire is a PHP profiler by SensioLabs, the Symfony2 guys https://blackfire.io/

If you use [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) to set up your virtual machine you'll be happy to know it's supported ;-)

## Xdebug and tracing memory usage

[XDEBUG2](http://xdebug.org/index.php) is a extension for PHP. Xdebug allows you to log all function calls, including parameters and return values to a file in different formats.There are three output formats. One is meant as a human readable trace, another one is more suited for computer programs as it is easier to parse, and the last one uses HTML for formatting the trace. You can switch between the two different formats with the setting. An example would be [available here](http://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-and-tracing-memory-usage.html)

## forp

[forp](http://anthonyterrien.com/forp/) simple, non intrusive, production-oriented, PHP profiler. Some of features are:

- measurement of time and allocated memory for each function
- CPU usage
- file and line number of the function call
- output as Google's Trace Event format
- caption of functions
- grouping of functions
- aliases of functions (useful for anonymous functions)

## DBG

[DBG](http://php-debugger.com/dbg/) is a a full-featured php debugger, an interactive tool that helps you debugging php scripts. It works on a production and/or development WEB server and allows you debug your scripts locally or remotely, from an IDE or console and its features are:

- Remote and local debugging
- Explicit and implicit activation
- Call stack, including function calls, dynamic and static method calls, with their parameters
- Navigation through the call stack with ability to evaluate variables in corresponding (nested) places
- Step in/Step out/Step over/Run to cursor functionality
- Conditional breakpoints
- Global breakpoints
- Logging for errors and warnings
- Multiple simultaneous sessions for parallel debugging
- Support for GUI and CLI front-ends
- IPv6 and IPv4 networks supported
- All data transferred by debugger can be optionally protected with SSL

Comment: That's *exactly* the information I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 101):

There's no direct way to get the memory usage of a single variable, but as Gordon suggested, you can use `memory_get_usage`. That will return the total amount of memory allocated, so you can use a workaround and measure usage before and after to get the usage of a single variable. This is a bit hacky, but it should work.

```
$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$foo = "Some variable";
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

Note that this is in no way a reliable method, you can't be sure that nothing else touches memory while assigning the variable, so this should only be used as an approximation.

You can actually turn that to an function by creating a copy of the variable inside the function and measuring the memory used. Haven't tested this, but in principle, I don't see anything wrong with it:

```
function sizeofvar($var) {
    $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
    $tmp = unserialize(serialize($var));
    return memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
}
```

Comment: `$tmp = $var` will create a shallow copy. This will not allocate more memory until $tmp is modified.

Comment: @Gordon, you're right, I kinda overlooked that point. As I cannot figure out a proper way to modify the variable without changing it's type or size, I'll leave that be. Perhaps someone can come up with a proper idea :)

Comment: how about `$tmp = unserialize(serialize($var))`; This would combine Aistina's approach above.

Comment: also, since `$var` is already a shallow copy or reference of what was passed to the function, you don't need `$tmp`, but can reassign to `$var`. This saves the internal reference from `$tmp` to `$var`.

Comment: Isn't there some more elegant way to dereference `$tmp` from `$var`?

Comment: I use that function as a static method of a Profiler class that I use during development/debugging to measure the size of variables.

Comment: This will **not** work on variables holding `Generators`. **Serialization of Generator is not allowed**

Answer (score 28):

No, there is not. But you can [`serialize($var)`](http://uk.php.net/serialize) and check the [`strlen`](http://uk.php.net/strlen) of the result for an approximation.

Comment: This is a much better approach, since it avoids the whole GC thing.

Comment: It's a terrible approximation. Every item in an array in PHP is ~80 bytes, yet `strlen(serialize(array(1,2,3)))` is 30.

Comment: @Aistina, -1. you are measuring the wrong thing. The variable and the serialized variable are two *totally* different things, and will give completely different results.

Comment: Not only that, but it'll fail *completely* on certain non-serializable data structures, e.g. circular references.

Answer (score 22):

In answer to Tatu Ulmanens answer:

It should be noted, that `$start_memory` itself will take up memory (`PHP_INT_SIZE * 8`).

So the whole function should become:

```
function sizeofvar($var) {
    $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
    $var = unserialize(serialize($var));
    return memory_get_usage() - $start_memory - PHP_INT_SIZE * 8;
}
```

Sorry to add this as an extra answer, but I can not yet comment on an answer.

Update: The *8 is not definate. It can depend apparently on the php version and possibly on 64/32 bit.

Comment: Can you explain why `* 8`? Thanks!

Comment: @sierrasdetandil It seems that $start_memory does not take up only `PHP_INT_SIZE` bytes, but `PHP_INT_SIZE*8`. You can try that by calling this function, it should return 0: `function sizeofvar() {
    $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
    return memory_get_usage() - $start_memory - PHP_INT_SIZE*8;
}`

Comment: `8` does not seems constant. Following your comment function on my dev system (PHP 5.6.19), it returns `-16`. Also, interestingly, from `php -a`, calling the function's two lines gives various different values.

Comment: @PaulDelRe yes, probably it is dependent on version/64bit this kind of stuff.

Comment: now the fatal error happens at the unserialize() call.  That's no help!  If a variable is so big it runs out of memory, calling a function on that variable will use up even MORE memory.  :(

Answer (score 6):

**You can't retrospectively calculate the exact footprint of a variable as two variables can share the same allocated space in the memory**

Let's try to share memory between two arrays, we see that allocating the second array costs half of the memory of the first one. When we unset the first one, nearly all the memory is still used by the second one.

```
echo memory_get_usage()."\n"; // <-- 433200
$c=range(1,100);
echo memory_get_usage()."\n"; // <-- 444348 (+11148)
$d=array_slice($c, 1);
echo memory_get_usage()."\n"; // <-- 451040 (+6692)
unset($c);
echo memory_get_usage()."\n"; // <-- 444232 (-6808)
unset($d);
echo memory_get_usage()."\n"; // <-- 433200 (-11032)
```

So we can't conclude than the second array uses half the memory, as it becomes false when we unset the first one.

For a full view about how the memory is allocated in PHP and for which use, I suggest you to read the following article: [How big are PHP arrays (and values) really? (Hint: BIG!)](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

The [Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) in the PHP documentation has also a lot of information about memory use, and references count to shared data segment.

The different solutions exposed here are good for approximations but none can handle the subtle management of PHP memory.

1. **calculating newly allocated space**

If you want the newly allocated space after an assignment, then you have to use `memory_get_usage()` before and after the allocation, as using it with a copy does give you an erroneous view of the reality.

```
// open output buffer
echo "Result: ";
// call every function once
range(1,1); memory_get_usage();

echo memory_get_usage()."\n";
$c=range(1,100);
echo memory_get_usage()."\n";
```

Remember that if you want to store the result of the first `memory_get_usage()`, the variable has to already exist before, and `memory_get_usage()` has to be called another previous time, and every other function also.

If you want to echo like in the above example, your output buffer has to be already opened to avoid accounting memory needed to open the output buffer.

2. **calculating required space**

If you want to rely on a function to calculate the required space to store a copy of a variable, the following code takes care of different optimizations:

```
<?php
function getMemorySize($value) {
    // existing variable with integer value so that the next line
    // does not add memory consumption when initiating $start variable
    $start=1;
    $start=memory_get_usage();
    // json functions return less bytes consumptions than serialize
    $tmp=json_decode(json_encode($value));
    return memory_get_usage() - $start;
}

// open the output buffer, and calls the function one first time
echo ".\n";
getMemorySize(NULL);

// test inside a function in order to not care about memory used
// by the addition of the variable name to the $_GLOBAL array
function test() {
    // call the function name once 
    range(1,1);

    // we will compare the two values (see comment above about initialization of $start)
    $start=1;
    $start=memory_get_usage();
    $c=range(1,100);
    echo memory_get_usage()-$start."\n";
    echo getMemorySize($c)."\n";
}
test();

// same result, this works fine.
// 11044
// 11044
```

Note that the size of the variable name matters in the memory allocated.

3. **Check your code!!**

A variable has a basic size defined by the inner C structure used in the PHP source code. This size does not fluctuate in the case of numbers. For strings, it would add the length of the string.

```
typedef union _zvalue_value {
    long lval;                  /* long value */
    double dval;                /* double value */
    struct {
        char *val;
        int len;
    } str;
    HashTable *ht;              /* hash table value */
    zend_object_value obj;
} zvalue_value;
```

If we do not take the initialization of the variable name into account, we already know how much a variable uses (in case of numbers and strings):

> 44 bytes in the case of numbers
>
> + 24 bytes in the case of strings
>
> + the length of the string (including the final NUL character)

*(those numbers can change depending on the PHP version)*

You have to round up to a multiple of 4 bytes due to memory alignment. If the variable is in the global space (not inside a function), it will also allocate 64 more bytes.

So if you want to use one of the codes inside this page, you have to check that the result using some simple test cases (strings or numbers) match those data taking into account every one of the indications in this post ($_GLOBAL array, first function call, output buffer, ...)

Comment: ...and that's even before we get into the internals of `zvalue`, `is_ref` and copy-on-write. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to you, I missed that page in the PHP Manual. I added the link to complete my answer (but I guess you already had read that).

Answer (score 4):

See:

- [`memory_get_usage()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) — Returns the amount of memory allocated to PHP
- [`memory_get_peak_usage()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) — Returns the peak of memory allocated by PHP

Note that this won't give you the memory usage of a specific variable though. But you can put calls to these function before and after assigning the variable and then compare the values. That should give you an idea of the memory used.

You could also have a look at the [PECL extension Memtrack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memtrack.php), though the documentation is a bit lacking, if not to say, virtually non-existent.

Comment: Yes. It can be used indirectly to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could opt for calculating memory difference on a callback return value. It's a more elegant solution available in PHP 5.3+.

```
function calculateFootprint($callback) {
    $startMemory = memory_get_usage();
    $result = call_user_func($callback);
    return memory_get_usage() - $startMemory;
}

$memoryFootprint = calculateFootprint(
    function() {
        return range(1, 1000000);
    }
);

echo ($memoryFootprint / (1024 * 1024)) . ' MB' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and the solution I used was to write the variable to a file then run filesize() on it. Roughly like this (untested code):

```
function getVariableSize ( $foo ) 
{
    $tmpfile = "temp-" . microtime(true) . ".txt";
    file_put_contents($tmpfile, $foo);
    $size = filesize($tmpfile);
    unlink($tmpfile);
    return $size;
}
```

This solution isn't terribly fast because it involves disk IO, but it should give you something much more exact than the memory_get_usage tricks. It just depends upon how much precision you require.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution only works for string and single dimension array of strings and that using `strlen` would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

The following script shows total memory usage of a single variable.

```
function getVariableUsage($var) {
  $total_memory = memory_get_usage();
  $tmp = unserialize(serialize($var));
  return memory_get_usage() - $total_memory; 
}

$var = "Hey, what's you doing?";
echo getVariableUsage($var);
```

Check this out

http://www.phpzag.com/how-much-memory-do-php-variables-use/

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but Xdebug traces with [xdebug.collect_assignment](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)s may be enough.

Comment: What this xdebug option do? How it will help to know size of particular variable?