# Optimize PHP scripts

Tags: php

Do you know if there's a way to log how much memory is used in PHP scripts?.

I would like a log that tells me which objects are using more memory, which functions I need to improve, etc.

It would be something like memory_get_usage but for each line of code.

Comment: `echo "MEMORY USAGE:  ". memory_get_usage()."<br>";` which is a start.

Comment: I mean something like that but I won't copy that for each line of code... I was asking if there's a way to do that automatically.

Comment: Maybe there's something in the manual for it http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php and Google the function. You may very well find something. But that's the function you need.

Comment: Already checked... there's nothing like the thing I'm looking for

Comment: This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2192657/ and http://blog.gigavoice.com/php-data-structures/ after Googling `"memory_get_usage() for individual items php"` where you'll find more, I am sure.

Comment: If you're looking to profile your code, look at using xdebug or xhprof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)'s [execution trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) might be closest to what you're looking for. It traces every include, function call and method call to a human-readable file that can optionally (with `xdebug.show_mem_delta` setting on) show the difference in memory usage between calls.