# PHP echo causes Apache to reach Timeout, related to output buffering

Tags: php, apache, timeout, echo, output-buffering

## Context

I have a website that runs on a LAMP architecture.

Basically, all HTML pages are pre-processed into one central php script. The output is only flushed at the very end of this script.

```
<?php
// PHP builds the HTML response as a string
$controller = new MasterController();
$html = $controller->render();

// Send headers
header('Content-Type: text/html');

// Send HTML response
echo $html;
?>
```

Server configuration :

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.4

# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Apr  1 2012 06:40:08

# php --version
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 26 2013 07:26:12)
```

## Issue

I recently discovered that sometimes, the script fails to exit.

In order to track down this issue, I created a `Timer` class built over `microtime()`, and adapted my script as follows :

```
<?php
// Initiate the microtime() timer
$timer = new Timer();

// PHP builds the HTML response as a string
$controller = new MasterController();
$html = $controller->render();

// Send headers
header('Content-Type: text/html');

// Send HTML response
$timer->log('Just before echo\'ing the $html variable');
echo $html;
$timer->log('Just after echo\'ing the $html variable');
?>
```

Most of the times, the execution will perform nicely :

```
Abs. (s)  Rel. (s)  Message
   0.000    +0.000  Timer __construct()'ed
...
   0.624    +0.624  Just before echo'ing the $html variable
   0.624    +0.000  Just after echo'ing the $html variable
   0.624    +0.000  Timer __destruct()'ed
```

But sometimes it will strangely freeze and timeout :

```
Abs. (s)  Rel. (s)  Message
   0.000    +0.000  Timer __construct()'ed
...
   0.612    +0.612  Just before echo'ing the $html variable
 120.709  +120.097  Timer __destruct()'ed
```

- Abs. (s) = Absolute time (in seconds) = Time elapsed from the creation of the timer until the current line of log.
- Rel. (s) = Relative time (in seconds) = Time elapsed from the previous line of log until the current line of log.

## Analysis

1. The "Timer __destruct()'ed" log line is written when the script ends. In the "freezing" case, the script execution seems to be aborted by the Apache Timeout directive (120 seconds). I verified that no other timeout was involved : setting Apache Timeout to 90 seconds will cause the abortion to occur after 90 seconds. Even PHP's max_execution_time, set to 30 seconds, doesn't prevent the script from reaching the 120 seconds of Apache Timeout.
2. When the failure occurs, the "Just after ..." line doesn't appears in the log, meaning that the echo command doesn't "terminate". I verified later that chunking my $html variable would allow the first few chunks to get out, then the freezing occurs at some "random" chunk. Mostly the `24 ko - 28 ko` chunk (for a 4 ko chunk size, or `24 ko - 32 ko` if chunk size is 8 ko), but not only.
3. I can't see any recurring pattern in the webpages involved. Huge pages (> 500 ko) are more likely to fail, but do not fail at every request. Small-sized pages (< 80 ko) may fail as well. The failure occurs rarely, compared to the amount of pages delivered by the website.

## Buffering

I tried to play on 3 different settings :

- PHP [output_buffering directive](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) (currently set to 4096)
- Apache [SendBufferSize directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#sendbuffersize) (currently set to 131071)
- Using manual [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) in the PHP script, with a chunk size of 4096 (aligned to the output_buffering value).

All those configs shown improvments (less pages freezing) but I was unable to completely eradicated the issue.

Help ?!

## Useful links

http://altroleet.com/blog/?p=54

http://www.binarytides.com/output-buffering-php-apache/

## Status

Currently trying with `SendBufferSize 1048576`, `output_buffering Off` and no chunks (`echo $html;`).

Comment: You did a really great job explaining the problem, but you forgot one thing.. the code.. please post the code for the `render()` method.

Comment: I couldn't possibly post the entire framework. Moreover, the issue is not in the processing, but in the final echo command, so I don't see the point.

Comment: Have you ever solved it? I am struggling with the exact same issue right now

Comment: Never... I'm still interested in any new information or context you could add !

Answer (score 1):

Try to measure memory usage of this script and see if there is a pattern

as it looks like echo can't handle this amount of data check this post for methods

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192689/1384300

also i think it may be related to this old bug

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18029

here is workaround which I found for this

```
function echobig($string, $bufferSize = 8192) {
  $splitString = str_split($string, $bufferSize);
  foreach($splitString as $chunk) {
    echo $chunk;
  }
}
```

and url where I found it

http://wonko.com/post/seeing_poor_performance_using_phps_echo_statement_heres_why

Comment: The last workaround you suggested is what I meant by "Using manual chunk_split()" at the end of my "Buffering" section. It shows improvments, but doesn't solve the issue. So far, i tried 8ko, 4ko and 128o chunks : most of them seems to freeze after a total of 23,5 ko multiples are sent.

Comment: have you tried to disable output_buffering entirely or manipulate with size of chunk while doing chunk_split()

Comment: I did :) roughly the same result. The best improvment seen so far was to raise SendBufferSize from 131071 to 1000000

Comment: echo is sending data to apache until it fill up its buffer when buffer is full echo is waiting until it will be empty and because this will never happen apache is terminating script. So I think you may need to increase this buffer even higher to the maximum size of your response if you run out of memory on apache you may want to install some caching mods http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mem_cache.html and enable caching of buffer

Comment: or you may want to change rendering function to not generate such a big strings in one go if that's possible

Comment: *This* is very intersting. Do you have any reference to support this ? Do you know if the Apache SendBuffer is shared among its threads ? Why would the SendBuffer getting emptied "never happen" ? // Limit the amount of HTML produced is indeed a good solution, but it will require more time.

Comment: here is some more info about buffering http://www.binarytides.com/output-buffering-php-apache/  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_buffer.html basically it never happen because of the request timeout and the way how this buffer works it just can't complete request so its blocking php. Unfortunately I'm not sure how this buffer is shared with threads or workers, maybe in your case that will be possible to disable this apache buffer and see if you still have problems with it, but I think this is the bottleneck of this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77739/discussion-between-francois-verry-and-zgr3doo).